# can a query be so fast that it skipped a row?

Tags: java, mysql, sql, jsp

I would like to ask if  a INSERT query be so fast that it skipped a row
and the resultset of SELECT statement after didn't get any returned value.

I am using percona xtradbcluster with proxysql.

TIA

Comment: No.  That is not how SQL works.  Please learn about ACID properties and databases.

Answer (score 0):

(ORDER BY fieldname DESC) see if the row comes out.  Or ASC if your already returning data using DESC.

Answer (score 0):

No. We'd be in a world of hurt if we couldn't rely on sql databases if they were too fast.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ACID